# despite of correct password sms is not sent in php using CURL

Tags: php, api, curl, sms

in following code segment i pass correct password and user name yet it show
ERROR username or password not set
please refer my code and say what is wrong with the code......

```
<?php
    $url = "https://sms2.cantech.in/api/api_http.php";
    $recipients = array('90XXXXXXXX');
    $param = array(
        'username' => 'cppcomputer',
        'password' => 'secret',
        'senderid' => 'SPRKNG',
        'text' => 'Hello World!',
        'route' => 'Informative',
        'type' => 'text',
        'datetime' => '2018-05-28 22:50:28',
        'to' => implode(';', $recipients),
    );
    $post = http_build_query($param, '', '&amp;');
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Connection: close"));
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    if(curl_errno($ch)) {
        $result = "cURL ERROR: " . curl_errno($ch) . " " . curl_error($ch);
    } else {
        $returnCode = (int)curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
        switch($returnCode) {
            case 200 :
                break;
            default :
                $result = "HTTP ERROR: " . $returnCode;
        }
    }
    curl_close($ch);
    print $result;
?>
```

Comment: Please attach the stacktrace / details of the exception you are getting. Thanks!

Comment: ERROR username or password not set.